# The referenced AMP URL is an independent AMP

Tags: amp-html

Why i get this error on Search Console? `The referenced AMP URL is an independent AMP`

This is the url that i put on my amp-page:

```
<link itemprop="url" rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/index.php?p=home" />
```

Comment: Based from this [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/9poTk3PtrGo), make sure that there is a link from the canonical version to the amp version. You may also check the https://validator.ampproject.org/ to [validate](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/troubleshooting/validation_errors) you page.

Comment: @Natalie Did you find solution for this issue ?

Comment: @Muhammed Yea, actually i got this error with the cannonical url pointing to the amp page, after i change it to the url that i showed on my question i got a a notification saying that i had this issue yet, but the Search Console was not correct. I just waited 2 weeks and the Search Console validated the fix.